# Listing elements awk

Tags: list, shell, multidimensional-array, awk

I have a list like this:

```
s1   d2
s1   d4
s3   d2
s4   d1
s1   d3 
s4   d1
s5   d6
s3   d5
s1   d2
s1   d3
```

I need to obtain, for every element in the first column (`s_`) the list of element in the second column (`d_`) in the same order of appearance. In this case:

```
s1  d2 d4 d3 d2 d3
s3  d2 d5
s4  d1 d1    
s5  d6
```

The order of the `s_` is not important, the order of the `d_` is.
Can you suggest a simple and fast approach to do it (because the list is large), maybe in awk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps (for the command line):

```
awk '{ vals[$1] = vals[$1] " " $2 }; END { for (key in vals) { print key,vals[key] }}' list
```

Formatted prettier as an awk script:

```
{ vals[$1] = vals[$1] " " $2 }
END {
    for (key in vals) {
        print key,vals[key]
    }
}
```

What this does is store, by index of the first values, a string that contains the progressive values on the right side. So each time it finds one, it concatenates it to the end of that string. Then at the end, it prints each pair out.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and is very straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an associative array to memorize the "sX" and then do string concatenation on the value.

```
BEGIN {
print "ID\tList\n";
}
{
id[$1]=id[$1] $2;
}
END{
for (var in id)
    print var,"\t",id[var];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
 awk '{ ss[$1]++ ; ds[$1 NR]=$2 } 
      END { for ( e in ss ) 
                { a=e 
                  for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) 
                      { a=a " " ds[e i] }  
                  printf("%s\n",gensub("  +"," ","g",a))
                }
      }' INPUTFILE
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This would guarantee the order of both keys and values:

```
awk 'END {
  for (i = 0; ++i <= c;)
    print idx[i], s[idx[i]]
  }
{
  s[$1] = s[$1] ? s[$1] OFS $2 : $2
  t[$1]++ || idx[++c] = $1
  }' infile
```